# AngularJS Checkboxes not toggling

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I am currently developing an application with AngularJS, and I have a list of items, with some checkboxes in it. In brief, it looks like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="a in b">
    <ul>
        <li ng-if="entry = 'someEntry'>
            ....
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myModel">
        </li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

The problem is that when I click the checkbox, it doesn't toggle. The model does toggle, and the checkbox also shows it's initial value. I've tested it on Chrome, Safari and Firefox, all on Mac OS X 10.9

My AngularJS version is 1.2.19

My entire code is:

```
<li ng-if="display == 'year' || display == 'month'">
    <ul ng-repeat="entry in data">
        <li ng-if="entry.type == 'WeekSeparator'">
            <div class="week-separator"><hr><span>Week {{entry.value}}</span></div>
        </li>

    <div ng-if="entry.type == 'Day'" class="entry-day">
        <li><a class="header">{{entry.value}}</a></li>

        <li ng-repeat="subEntry in entry.subEntries">
                <a>
                    <div class="width-92">
                        <select ng-model="schedule.entries[subEntry.id].hour">
                        <option value="0">Hele Dag</option>
                        <option value="1">1e Uur</option>
                        <option value="2">2e Uur</option>
                        <option value="3">3e Uur</option>
                        <option value="4">4e Uur</option>
                        <option value="5">5e Uur</option>
                        <option value="6">6e Uur</option>
                        <option value="7">7e Uur</option>
                        <option value="8">8e Uur</option>
                        <option value="9">9e Uur</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-1">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="schedule.entries[subEntry.id].description"  placeholder="Beschrijving">
                </div>
                <div class="width-64">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="schedule.entries[subEntry.id].ond"> Ond.
                </div>
                <div class="width-64">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="schedule.entries[subEntry.id].bov"> Bov.
                </div>
                <div class="width-64">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="schedule.entries[subEntry.id].doc"> Doc.
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
</li>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PR3Ww/

Comment: try using `ng-change` instead of `ng-click`.If it still doesn't work plz provide a jsfiddle of you code

Comment: Is there some issues in here `<li ng-if="entry = 'someEntry'>`? Should it be `<li ng-if="entry == 'someEntry'">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until now, I don't know why, but your `<a>` tag is destorying your scope within the inner ng-repeat.

Take a look at: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PR3Ww/3/)

Comment: That solved it! I needed to write this functionality for a website that used `a`'s in their lists, so I had to use it. But I changed some CSS rules and it works now

Answer (score 2):

ng-repeat creates a childscope. The binding for the checkbox ng-model="myModel" will not update the $scope, it will update the child scope of ng-repeat. There's a good read about this topic here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-repeat

As a rule of thumb always use a '.' in your models like

```
    $scope.obj = { myModel :  true };
```

and in your HTML

```
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="obj.myModel" />
```

Comment: But I use a subobject. And the problem isn't that all checkboxes are checked at the same moment, the problem is that they don't change

Comment: OK, created a JSFiddle, posted in main post. It uses a dump of my application's data

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using older version of HTML and in that version  inside is not allowed. 
HTML 4.01 specifies that  elements may only contain inline elements. A  is a block element, so it may not appear inside an .

Comment: No, that wasn't it, I added <!DOCTYPE html>. The answer boindiil gave me solved the problem